# ASP.NET CORE LINUX Get CPU USAGE

Tags: asp.net-core

With this code, this works for windows. For Linux(Ubuntu) "PerformanceCounter is not provided in Linux"

```
PerformanceCounter counter = GetPerfCounterForProcessId(process.Id); //Just gets process by id dont worry...
var processUsages = counter.NextValue();
double processUsage = counter.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;
```

How could I transfer this method to get the CPU Usage from a process by ID with it working in Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PerformanceCounter` **represents a Windows NT performance counter component** that means it only works on Windows and listen on Windows Performance Monitor.

For `Linux`, you should use the `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()` to calculate CPU Usage. Example:

```csharp
var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
var startCpuUsage = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
// Start watching CPU
stopWatch.Start();

// Measure something else, such as .Net Core Middleware
await _next.Invoke(httpContext);

// Stop watching to mensure
stopWatch.Stop();
var endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
var endCpuUsage = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;

var cpuUsedMs = (endCpuUsage - startCpuUsage).TotalMilliseconds;
var totalMsPassed = (endTime - startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
var cpuUsageTotal = cpuUsedMs / (Environment.ProcessorCount * totalMsPassed);

var cpuUsagePercentage = cpuUsageTotal * 100;
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the overall CPU usage (not for a specific process)?

Comment: To get the overall CPU usage, get all processes with `Process.GetProcesses()` and compute the sum of the processor times.

Comment: but you can't access other containers sometimes and go over GetProcesses(), what would yo do then?