# How can retrieve information about RAM,CPU, Disk usage from asp.net core on linux OS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-standard

I need to retrieve total usage of system resource. On similar/other question told about calculation for specific process but I need info about total resource usage in system like in "Task Manager".  Environment is asp.net core API on Ubuntu 20.01.  How I can get it? I didn't find any info in documentation for .net core/asp.net core  >3.0.

Comment: Is this answer you are looking for?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945915/asp-net-core-linux-get-cpu-usage#:~:text=PerformanceCounter%20counter%20%3D%20GetPerfCounterForProcessId(process.,NextValue()%3B%20double%20processUsage%20%3D%20counter.

Comment: I known with info from this answer but as I can understand it's about single process and calculation usage for specific task id not for all system. Maybe I have misunderstood... But example of code whit usage wich described in this answer didn't give opportunity to get full info from system. Glad to have help from someone to explain how it use if I wrong with this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple API for this, however you can read /proc/stat and calculate the CPU usage your self.

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/get-cpu-usage#2-getting-cpu-usage-using-procstat