# current CPU usage percentage Linux in C#

Tags: c#, linux, cpu-usage

I'm trying to report a total CPU usage in a Linux system. It reports every 10 seconds. I have multiple processes running on several dockers so running `Process.GetProcesses()` got me an error of `unable to retrieve the specified information about the process. it may have exited or may be privileged.` My computer has 12 CPUs and 2 for every thread: [image: computer specs]        meaning it is using 6 cores. I need an efficient way to calculate current CPU usage of all the computer at given time.
My attempts have been:

`TimeSpan delta = DateTime.Now - _lastTimeBuildReport;`
`double cpuLoad = 100* (currentExporterDic["node_cpu_seconds_total"].GetSum("idle") - _previousExporterDic["node_cpu_seconds_total"].GetSum("idle")) / delta.TotalSeconds;`

Which gave me strange values (3 times what is real)
And this which gave the error, after [ASP.NET CORE LINUX Get CPU USAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945915/asp-net-core-linux-get-cpu-usage)

```
private double CalculateToTotalCPUUsage(double totalMsPassed)
{
  try
     {
       double totalCpuUsagePercentage = 0;
       string getProccesorsCoresCMD = "grep 'cpu cores' /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}'";
       string[] coresLines = DotNetUtilities.DotNetUtilities.GetOsCmdLineOutput(getProccesorsCoresCMD).Lines;
       int cpuCores = int.Parse(coresLines[0]);
       Process[] allProc = Process.GetProcesses();
       foreach (Process process in allProc)
       {
         // Start watching CPU
         var currentProStartCpuUsage = process.TotalProcessorTime;

         //Delay the function so we can measure the same CPU load
                    
        Task.Delay(Convert.ToInt32(totalMsPassed)).Wait();
        var currentProEndCpuUsage = process.TotalProcessorTime;
        var currentProCpuUsedMs = (currentProEndCpuUsage - currentProStartCpuUsage).TotalMilliseconds;
        var currentProCpuUsageTotal = currentProCpuUsedMs / (cpuCores * totalMsPassed);
        var currentProCpuUsagePercentage = currentProCpuUsageTotal * 100;
        totalCpuUsagePercentage += currentProCpuUsagePercentage;
       }
                
     return totalCpuUsagePercentage;
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
       Logger.LogError($"Couldn't calculate total CPU usage. Reason: {ex.Message} {ex.StackTrace}");
        return -1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Intel Core i5-10500 has 6 cores according to my fav hardware selling site. And 12 threads. So the display of your info is a bit ambigious, right? It should show 6 cores with 2 threads.

Comment: I wrote that it meant there are 6 cores, there is a different between cores and CPUs. When I ran Environment.ProcessorCount it also told me 12

Comment: Since you already using _grep_, maybe using _top_ would benefit as well?

Comment: won't a bash command take too long? I'm going to get that core to a place where it isn't calculated every 10 seconds

Comment: the `perf` command might give you an alternate means to explore what you try to explore.